# Scala's match/case for Option[classOf[...]]

Tags: scala, match

I need to check the returned type from a method to invoke different methods.
This is the code:

```
class X ...
class Y ...

...

def getType(input:String) : Option[Class[_]] = {
  if ... return Some(classOf[X])
  if ... return Some(classOf[Y])
  ...
}

getType(input) match {
  case Some(classOf[X]) => ... // ERROR
  case Some(classOf[Y]) => ...
  case None => ...
}
```

However, I got errors:

[image]

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can't use `classOf` inside the structural match. Instead you can add a condition which checks for that.

```
val opt: Option[Class[_]] = Some(classOf[Int])

opt match {
  case Some(c) if c == classOf[String] => "String"
  case Some(c) if c == classOf[Int] => "Int"
  case None => "No Class"
  case _ => "Some other Class"
} //yields Int
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
getType(input) match {
  case Some(x: Class[X]) => ... 
  case Some(y: Class[Y]) => ...
  case None => ...
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this suffer from type-erasure? I think it does not work.

Comment: Ha, if you mistype it `case Some(Class[Foo])` you get `unsupported pattern: TypeTree / p3: Class[Foo] @ Class[Foo] (this is a scalac bug.)`